# "Method in class cannot be applied to given types" error when trying to call method

Tags: java, arrays, reverse, palindrome

I'm new here so if my question is wrong somehow let me know and I apologize in advance.

I'm creating a program for taking user input, putting it into an array and then reverse the arrays and checking for palindromes.  The program will then print the palindromes from 101 to the user input number.  Right now I just want to check if the loop I created for reversing the arrays is working, but when I call on the method I get the error

```
"method reverseArray in class Palindrome cannot be applied to given types"
required: char[]
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal arguments differ in length
```

Here is the code (bottom three methods are empty right now because I haven't gotten to writing them yet).

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    Scanner promptUser = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter an Integer greater than 100: ");
    Integer userInt = new Integer(promptUser.nextInt());
    String userString = userInt.toString();
    char[] charUser = userString.toCharArray();

    if (userInt <= 100)
    {    
        System.out.print("That integer is not greater than 100,"
                        + " restart program and try again!");
    }

    System.out.println(reverseArray());
}

/**Takes the integer provided by the user and turns it into a string 
 * then takes that string and puts it into a char[], then there is a for loop 
 * to reverse that array.
 * @param userArray array used to store the reversed string.
 * @revArray char array used to store data from charChange array.
 * @return returns charChange now with the reversed string.
 */
public static char[] reverseArray(char[] userArray)
{
    char[] revArray = new char[userArray.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < revArray.length; i++)
    {
        userArray[i] = revArray[revArray.length - 1 - i];
    }

    return userArray;    
}

public static boolean arraysAreEqual(char[] arrayPal1, char[] arrayPal2) 
{

} 

public static boolean isPrime(int Primes)
{

}

public void printArray(char[] charChange)
{

}
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear; you're calling `reverseArray` without providing a `char[]` as an argument.

Comment: also: even if you don't implement them yet, for each method with a returntype, there should be a return statement.

Comment: Did you try to read error message?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't pass any paramter to function, and it expect array as a paramter:

```
reverseArray(charUser);
```

and are you expecting to print the array through

```
System.out.println(reverseArray());
```

this will print the address for the array, you will have to loop over the array elements to print it, something like:

```
char[] resultArray = reverseArray(charUser);

for(int i = 0; i < resultArray.length; i++)
{
   System.out.println(resultArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: That definitely eliminated the error, but now when I run the program, it doesn't print out the reversed array.  Sorry, trying to post the edited code.

Comment: because you have a problem in the reverse function edit to be:  revArray[i] = userArray[userArray.length - 1 - i];  and change return to be return revArray;